# Matplotlib specific marker (rotation symbol)

Tags: python, matplotlib, marker

I'm wondering what is this marker name (I couldn't discover so far):

[image]

And if there is the opposite one (arrow rotated in clock-wise direction)

From [that](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/line_styles.html) example.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's using latex (or rather, matplotlib's builtin "mathtex") to plot `$\circlearrowleft$`. The opposite direction would be `$\circlearrowright$'.

As a quick example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.scatter(*np.random.random((2, 5)), s=200, marker=r'$\circlearrowleft$')
ax.scatter(*np.random.random((2, 5)), s=200, marker=r'$\circlearrowright$')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I knew that was mathtex, but I didn't know the name of this symbol in english. Thank you again. (: